# Modify Global Posts Plugin

Tags: query

I am trying to modify a query from wpmudev called global blog posts .  I need it to not show any of the default blog posts, the first post on each blog.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "site_posts 
WHERE blog_public = '1' 
AND post_type ='" . $recentglobalpoststype . "' 
ORDER BY post_published_stamp 
DESC LIMIT " . $recentglobalpostsnumber;
```

I need to suppress the default blog post from each blog. Any ideas, I tried

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "site_posts 
WHERE blog_public = '1' 
AND post_type ='" . $recentglobalpoststype . "' 
AND ID <> 1 
ORDER BY post_published_stamp 
DESC LIMIT " . $recentglobalpostsnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the SQL OFFSET statement:

OFFSET 1

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "site_posts 
WHERE blog_public = '1' 
AND post_type ='" . $recentglobalpoststype . "' 
ORDER BY post_published_stamp 
OFFSET 1
DESC LIMIT " . $recentglobalpostsnumber;
```

Comment: No unfortunately the OFFSET 1 crashed the site.  So I had to remove it to fix it.